# Error in Sequence Generator: StopIteration: list index out of range

Tags: python, keras

I am using sequence generator in keras to parallelly fetch data from the disk but I am getting a very odd error.

So, this is my code for the sequence generator

```
class detracSequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, bbox_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y, self.bbox = x_set, y_set, bbox_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print 'index range', idx*self.batch_size, 'till', (idx+1)*self.batch_size
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_bbox = self.bbox[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

#        print batch_x
        imgs = np.ndarray((self.batch_size,128,128,3))
        for file_index in range(self.batch_size):
            temp = cv2.imread(batch_x[file_index])
            if temp.shape[0] == 0:
                print '1', batch_x[file_index]

           # print '1', temp.shape
            #print(temp)
            x1, x2, x3, x4 =  batch_bbox[file_index,0],batch_bbox[file_index,1],batch_bbox[file_index,2], batch_bbox[file_index,3]
            #print batch_x[file_index]
            temp_ = temp[int(x2):int(x4),int(x1):int(x3)]
            imgs[file_index] = cv2.resize(temp_,(128,128))

        return imgs, np.array(batch_y)
```

and this is the code for calling this generator.

```
Xtrain_gen = detracSequence(X_train,y_train,training_coordinates, batch_size=32)
history = model.fit_generator(generator=Xtrain_gen, epochs=20, validation_data=Xvalidation_gen,callbacks=callbacks_list,use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Now, the issue is that the value of idx is generated by internal code. My expectation is that it will handle the index bound. But in the method **getitem**(self, idx), I am getting a value of idx which is given me index out of range error as given below, which is bit wierd. Here's the error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finetuneInceptionV3.py", line 112, in <module>
    history = model.fit_generator(generator=Xtrain_gen, epochs=20, validation_data=Xvalidation_gen,callbacks=callbacks_list,use_multiprocessing=True)
  File "/home/sfarkya/tfenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sfarkya/tfenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2192, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/home/sfarkya/tfenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 584, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)
  File "/home/sfarkya/tfenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
StopIteration: list index out of range
```

Now, I don't know to resolve this without getting into source code but I don't expect this to happen. Can anyone tell me if am missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that your data can perfectly be divided by the `batch_size`, this might not necessarily be the case as the last batch might be smaller than `batch_size` as your using a slice. Instead of having a fixed range, use the size of slice:

```
imgs = np.ndarray((len(batch_x),128,128,3)) # here
for file_index in range(len(batch_x)): # and here
  temp = cv2.imread(batch_x[file_index])
```

so you never index higher than what you have.

Comment: Ohh right! I got blindsided by the fact that it might be an integer and as I was using ceil it was always giving me an integer. Thanks for the help :), it seems like my blunder.